# How to release bridge object after C++ callback is called from Objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c, callback, cocos2d-x

I'm creating an app in C++ using cocos2d-x. For some integration work, I need to call Objective C code, with an asynchronous response implemented by calling a C++ callback method from Objective C.

<sup><sub>TLDR; how should I release the C++ to Objective C bridge whenever the callback finishes? Should I implement the bridge as a static member variable?</sub></sup>

For the basic C++ to Objective C part, I've followed [Jesús Bosch's lead](https://web.archive.org/web/20130630145324/http://www.jesusbosch.com/2012/07/communication-between-c-and-objective-c.html), for the calling of a C++ callback from Objective C, I've followed his [colleagues post](http://www.plungeinteractive.com/blog/2012/08/05/obj-c-to-cpp-callbacks/).

Basically, I've ended up with the following setup.

First, we have `MyApp.h`

```
class MyApp
{
public:
    static void buttonChosen(int index);
    void callObjC();
    // ...
}
```

and `MyApp.cpp`, which is responsible for initiating the Objective C code.

```
void MyApp::buttonChosen(int index)
{
    log("Button choosen: %d", index);
}

void MyApp::callObjC()
{
    iOSBridge::iOSHelper* bridge = new iOSBridge::iOSHelper();
    bridge->ShowAlert(buttonChosen);        
    // delete bridge;
}
```

Then, I have the bridge, `iOSBridge.h`

```
namespace iOSBridge{
    class iOSHelper {    
    public:
        void(*callback)(int index);

        iOSHelper() { }
        void ShowAlert(void(*callback)(int));    
    };    
}
```

and its implementation `iOSHelper.cpp`

```
#include "iOSHelper.h"
#import "IsolatedAlert.h"

namespace iOSBridge{    
    void iOSHelper::ShowAlert(void(*callback)(int index))
    {
        this->callback = callback;
    IsolatedAlert* instance = [IsolatedAlert new];
    [instance showAlert: this];
    }
}
```

Finally, there is the `IsolatedAlert.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "iOSHelper.h"

typedef struct iOSBridge::iOSHelper iOsType;

@interface IsolatedAlert : UIViewController
-(void)showAlert:(iOsType*)callback;
@end
```

and its implementation `IsolatedAlert.mm`

```
#import "IsolatedAlert.h"

iOsType* staticPointer;

@implementation IsolatedAlert
-(void)showAlert:(iOsType*)callback
{
    staticPointer = callback;

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title?"
                                                    message:@"Message?"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    staticPointer->callback(buttonIndex);
}
@end
```

Now, my question is this: how should I release `iOSBridge::iOSHelper* bridge` whenever the `buttonChosen()` is called? Is implementing it as a static member ok, as long as I promise not to have more than one instance of `MyApp` instantiated at any one time? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual [C++ way of releasing an instance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_%28C++%29#Releasing_dynamically_allocated_memory) created with `new` is to use the `delete` keyword:

```
void MyApp::buttonChosen(int index)
{
    log("Button choosen: %d", index);

    delete bridge;
    bridge = NULL;
}
```

It is good practice to `NULL` the pointer after delete to ensure the application behaves in a consistent manner (crash) in case the object is used after `delete`. If you don't do that, your application may seem to work for a while, produce incorrect results, show weird behavior, or crash randomly, or all of the aforementioned.

Ah and of course you should make the bridge pointer a member variable of your App class.

```
#include "iOSHelper.h"

class MyApp
{
public:
    static void buttonChosen(int index);
    void callObjC();
    // ...

protected:
    iOSBridge::iOSHelper* bridge;
}
```

You should also consider making the existing methods `protected` or `private` because buttonChosen is probably not a method you want to be able to be called from outside the MyApp instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @LearnCocos2d! I'll take all of your advices and give it a go. :) +1